# Testing authentication in react with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I need to write a test in react using jest and enzyme and I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoggedOutRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
    <Route render={() => (
        !isLoggedIn
            ? <Component {...rest} />
            : <Redirect to='/habits' />
    )} />
)

export default LoggedOutRoute;
```

with the following test:

```
import LoggedOutRoute from '.';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { component } from 'react';

describe('LoggedOutRoute', () => {
    let component;

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<LoggedOutRoute />);
    })

    test('it renders', () => {
        expect(component.find('Route')).toHaveLength(1)
    })
    
    test('it exists', () => {
        expect(component.find('LoggedOutRoute').exists()).toBeFalsy();
    })

    test('it redirects to /habits link', () => {
    let links = component.find('Redirect');
    expect(links).toHaveLength(0)
    })

    test('It should return logged in for a false statement', () => {
        let LoggedOutRoute = component.find('Route')
        expect(LoggedOutRoute).toHaveLength(1)
    })

    test('')

})
```

I need to write a test to test for '!isLoggedIn', i'm not sure how to structure this at all, it's for authentication and when i'm running coverage - line 5 is what is letting me down. I'm not sure exactly how to test the ternary.

Comment: How are we supposed to know which line do you mean by the 5th?

Comment: by counting from 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

You should basically mount it with a truthy/falsy prop and test whether it renders accordingly: `component = shallow(<LoggedOutRoute isLoggedIn={true} />);`

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark it as the correct answer / +1...

Comment: Hi, apologies, it did not work. I don't know if i wrote it wrong but i'll show you.

Comment: beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<LoggedOutRoute isLoggedIn={true}/>);
    })

Comment: test('It should return logged in for a false statement', () => {
        let LoggedOutRoute = component.find('Route')
        expect(LoggedOutRoute).toHaveLength(1)
    })